# How can I combine two columns from two tables with different length based on ID?

Tags: r

I have two tables with different information but for the same individuals and the tables also have different length. The tables look something like this:

```
DT1 <- data.table(ID = c(1,2,3,5),
                 exit1 = c(NA, "01/02/2016", "01/10/2010", "01/01/2016"),
                 value = c(2,4,5,4))
DT1
       ID    exit1    value
    1:  1       <NA>     2
    2:  2 01/02/2016     4
    3:  3 01/10/2010     5
    4:  5 01/01/2016     4
```

and

```
DT2 <- data.table(ID = 1:5,
                 exit2 = c("31/01/2016", "01/01/2021", "30/09/2019", "31/12/2015", "30/09/2020"),
                 text = c("a","b","c","a","e"))
DT2
      ID      exit2      text
        1:  1 31/01/2016    a
        2:  2 01/01/2021    b
        3:  3 30/09/2019    c
        4:  4 31/12/2015    a
        5:  5 30/09/2020    e
```

What I would like to do is to overwrite the values in DT2 column 2 (exit2) with the values from DT1 (exit1) based on the ID. If there is a value in exit1 it should overwrite exit2, otherwise the value in exit2 should be kept.

The result should look like this:

```
ID      exit2 text
1:  1 31/01/2016    a
2:  2 01/02/2016    b
3:  3 01/10/2010    c
4:  4 31/12/2015    a
5:  5 01/01/2016    e
```

Could anyone help how I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need merge.data.table(DT1, DT2, by = "ID", all=T)